# Authentication failing in Checkmarx SonarQube Plugin 8.60

Tags: sonarqube, checkmarx

Is there any compatibility issue with Sonarqube Version 6.7 and Checkmarx SonarQube Plugin 8.60.0?

We were successfully using Checkmarx 8.41 with Sonarqube 4.5.7, without any issues. But ever since our environment is upgraded to  Sonarqube 6.7.2 (build 37468) and Checkmarx plugin 8.60.0, Chcekmarx authentication is failing in Sonarqube UI (Administration > Checkmarx -> Checkmarx Configuration), same credentials work fine in Checkmarx web console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we managed to get this issue resolved and rootcause of the issue seemed to be trivial and silly :)
This version of sonar-checkmarx plugin expect escape character before username like 
`<<donamin>>\\<<windows username>>`.

Hope this helps others facing similar issues.